# Pipe merge multiple pandas dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pipe

Suppose I generate three pandas dataframes which I want to merge:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2),
                   columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = df1.assign(b= np.random.randn(10)).rename(columns={'a': 'z', 'b': 'd'})
df3 = df2.assign(d= np.random.randn(10)).rename(columns={'z': 'f', 'd': 'e'})
```

This yields the following three dataframes:

```
df1:
      a         b
0  1.919799  1.067477
1  0.719339  1.695729
2 -0.957719  0.967126
3  0.071723 -0.171463
4 -1.168568  0.193577
5  1.422793  0.947829
6  1.491163 -1.053055
7 -0.453266  0.151310
8  0.265600  0.579668
9 -0.379263 -0.971077

df2:
          z         d
0  1.919799 -1.026633
1  0.719339 -0.032280
2 -0.957719 -1.005391
3  0.071723 -1.279660
4 -1.168568 -0.342792
5  1.422793  0.265616
6  1.491163  0.110747
7 -0.453266  0.324986
8  0.265600 -1.557793
9 -0.379263  0.950179

df3:
          f         e
0  1.919799  2.440809
1  0.719339 -0.281359
2 -0.957719  0.278984
3  0.071723 -0.509653
4 -1.168568 -2.663583
5  1.422793  0.410250
6  1.491163  1.532236
7 -0.453266 -0.043323
8  0.265600 -1.078704
9 -0.379263 -0.569662
```

Next, I do the following:

1. Merge df1 and df2 by column a and z (which are the same but with different name). Hence, I cannot do a df.join.
2. Pipe this into a lambda function, which merges the combined df1 and df2 from point 1 with df3 (which has a third column f which is the same as z. I.e., note that 'a', 'z' and 'f' are the same variables.

My code for the merge operation is as follows:

```
df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['a'], right_on=['z'], how='left')\
    .pipe(lambda df_: pd.merge(df_, df3, left_on=['z'], right_on=['f'], how='left'))\
    .drop(['z', 'f'], axis=1)
```

My question is therefore, if this is the optimal way to merge these three dataframes.

My main goal is to avoid having to use several lines of codes and instead use the pipe operator, so that I can keep manipulating df4, but if other possibilities exists please let me know!

I am used to coding in R, and therefore I like the framework of the pipe %>% operator.

The final output is:

```
          a         b         d         e
0  1.919799  1.067477 -1.026633  2.440809
1  0.719339  1.695729 -0.032280 -0.281359
2 -0.957719  0.967126 -1.005391  0.278984
3  0.071723 -0.171463 -1.279660 -0.509653
4 -1.168568  0.193577 -0.342792 -2.663583
5  1.422793  0.947829  0.265616  0.410250
6  1.491163 -1.053055  0.110747  1.532236
7 -0.453266  0.151310  0.324986 -0.043323
8  0.265600  0.579668 -1.557793 -1.078704
9 -0.379263 -0.971077  0.950179 -0.569662
```

**Update:**
Thanks for your responses.

Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my original question.

I am primarily interested in avoiding the usage of the pd. command (such as pd.concat), since I want to left join after I have done manipulation of the data, for example after a .assign. That is the reason for using the .pipe operator.

In this regard, I cannot use the df3.join operation, as I have different names for two identical columns. Furthermore, if I want to be able to do multi-indexes merging with .join, I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: merging with both multi-indexes is not implemented
```

Hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: I would recommend you put some test data and expected output in your question.  This will help us help you better.  Look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, without using `.pipe`, and arguably more readable:

```
df4 = df1.merge(df2.rename_axis({'z':'a'}, axis=1),
                on='a',
                how='left').merge(df3.rename_axis({'f':'a'}, axis=1),
                                  on='a',
                                  how='left')
```

By renaming the join column in `df2` and `df3`, you can join on a common column name and avoid having to drop them afterwards. As the first `merge` operation returns a `DataFrame` object, you can build on that with another `merge` operation.